How do I set up catch-all routes in Next.js 14 to handle multiple URL segments
I am currently working on a project with NextJS 14, and I need to set up catch-all routes for handling multiple URL segments. I read the official documentation, but I still do not understand the implementation details clearly.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I want to create dynamic route that can capture any number of segments in URL. For example, I want route that can match paths like:
/blog/[...slug] (this should handle /blog/2024/10/my-first-post)
/products/[...slug] (this should handle /products/category/item-name)

you examples are correct. Refer this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments. Still not sure what you want

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Abass Dev What do you want to do after catching those segments ? What will you show if URL is /blog/2024 or /blog/2024/10 or /products/category?
